# how to store html contents in database using laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store `html` table into my `database` but it is throwing this `error`

> array to string conversion

**i'm posting html table from `javascript` to my `php` controller**

```
var html = '<table><thead><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Alphabet</td><td>200</td></tr></tbody></table>; 

 $.ajax({
    url:'store',
    type:'POST',
    data:{table:html},
    success:function(data){
       console.log(data)
    }
 });
```

**laravel**:posted data to be inserted

```
 Route::post('store',function(){

   $toStore = addslashes(['table' => $_POST['table']]);   

   \App\product_table::create($toStore);

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) expects string and you pass an array to the function.

You can just pass request array to the `create()` method:

```
\App\product_table::create(request()->all());
```

If you want to use `addslashes()` anyway, do this:

```
\App\product_table::create(['table' => addslashes(request('table'))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `addslashes` function accept only strings, and you have to use [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#accessing-the-request) class in order to get your submitted data:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

Route::post('store',function(Request $request) {

    $toStore = ['table' => addslashes($request->input('table'))];   

    \App\product_table::create($toStore);

});
```

Comment: You've copy-pasted `['table' => addslashes(...)]` from my answer, but you've forgot to remove extra `)` from the end.